# Rails: ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken when adding a Image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am new to Ruby-on-rails and I am currently working on a project that let a user log in to add,create update delete a Marvel character. Each  characters have a name, description, origin, alliance and image.
I used Carrierwave for file upload.

I used the scaffold command and everything was working fine, until I decided to be able to create and update my characters on the same page using .js.erb files instead of having to redirect the user to 2 different pages for the create and the update.

I have the following error everytime I try to create a character with a image. everything works fine when I don't add a image:
*ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken*

I know that there are a few different other similar questions already asked on the forum but I can't seem to find the answer to my problem.

I am using Rails 4.2.6.
I tried to add the gem remotipart but it didn't fix my issue.

create.js.erb code:

```
$("#characters").append("<%= escape_javascript(render @character)%>");
```

create action in the controller:

```
 def create
@character = Character.new(character_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @character.save
    format.html { redirect_to @character, notice: 'Character was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @character }
    format.js
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @character.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }

  end
end
```

end

I hope I provide enough information, thanks in advance!

Edit:
Here is the code I have in the form.html.erb that let the users add a image:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :image %>
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
    <% if f.object.image %>
        <%= image_tag f.object.image.url %>
        <!--<%= f.label :remove_image %>
    <%= f.check_box :remove_image %> -->
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

Comment: Could you show us then view containing the form ?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

```
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
```

Put this in your controller

Comment: Thank you it work! I can't believe it was that easy... Could you possibly give further explanation on why my program need that line of code now but was working fine without it before? I appreciate your answer but I don't just want to past that line without understanding it, and knowing the impact it have. thanks

Comment: authenticity_token is used so that when params are passed to the server they are authenticated and the server knows they are what are expected. However some gems use data not "valid" through that token. It's not a good habit to do this kind of skips but sometimes it has to be done and I've done it on some of my apps you just need to know what you are doing

Comment: IMHO, bypassing security without understanding what's happening just to have the pseudo answer accepted is not helping him in the long term..

Comment: disabling the physical lock on your door would be pretty stupid, seems like the same logic would apply here.

Answer (score 3):

I think your Rails forms now will not render the CSRF field in the form:

```
<%= form_for @character, :remote => true, :authenticity_token => true,:multipart => true do |f| %>

..... 

<% end %>
```

Comment: Works for me with Rails 5.1, remote form (simple_form) and CarrierWave without remotipart.